# CSS - pictures are not displayed

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby 1.9.2 Rails 3.1

I've tried it in 3 different projects and the same thing happens:

1. css file is copied to /assets/stylesheets
2. images are copied to /assets/images
3. stylesheet is applied to all the pages (good)
4. images from /assets/images are not dispplayed

I've checked css files and all of them have have images included like this

```
#wrapper {
    background: url(images/img02.jpg) no-repeat left top;
```

Any ideas while files are not displayed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm correct, your css file is in the directory /assets/stylesheet/
So if you put in that stylesheet, an url, it will look for the given file, in the current directory, the stylesheets/ directory.

You are looking for ../images/img02.jpg, so

```
    #wrapper {
        background: url('../images/img02.jpg') no-repeat left top;
```

Comment: Thanks, it work. There is another thing that drives me completely nuts - I want to replace the css with the new one. So I delete the style.css file ans all associated images.
I copy the new ones in stead of them.... and I still have the old css loaded even if after reloading the webrick. Anyi ideas?

Comment: This is the cache of your browser. Empty your temp. internet files, hit Ctrl+F5 or add a querystring in your html, instead of refering to `assets/stylesheets/style.css`, refer to `assets/stylesheets/style.css?v1` and increment the number every time

Answer (score 3):

You are not directing them to the correct folder. Your css is looking for a folder called "images" within the assets/stylesheets folder. Try adding this to your code:

```
../
```

So it will look like this:

```
#wrapper {
    background: url(../images/img02.jpg) no-repeat left top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it work. There is another thing that drives me completely nuts - I want to replace the css with the new one. So I delete the style.css file ans all associated images.
I copy the new ones in stead of them.... and I still have the old css loaded even if after reloading the webrick. Any ideas?

Comment: Hit ctrl+F5, this will clear the browser cache, see if that works.

Comment: @ Kyle Sevenoaks That's pretty obvious - hence I didn't mentioned it. Of course I tries it and it still doesn't work. I think the problem is that rails compile all css into single style and then holds it somewhere, I just can't figure out where

Answer (score 3):

Paths in your CSS file are relative to the path of the CSS file itself.  So you're looking for your image file in assets/stylesheets/images.  Change the style to:

```
background: url(../images/img02.jpg) no-repeat left top;
```

Comment: Thanks, it work. There is another thing that drives me completely nuts - I want to replace the css with the new one. So I delete the style.css file ans all associated images.
I copy the new ones in stead of them.... and I still have the old css loaded even if after reloading the webrick. Any ideas?